# what debug=myapp:* npm start does?

Tags: node.js

what `debug=myapp:* npm start` does? I know know what `npm start`  does. `DEBUG=myapp` seem to set a environment varible. However I don't understand how they are linked and useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project most probably uses [`debug`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) package, I'd give the package's docs a read. The `debug` env variable is used to narrow down the debugging info you're getting out of your app.